How to populate a nested class in a LINQ query
I need help writing this linq query.
I have this class:
public class ClassProva
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public ClassSeconda Seconda { get; set; } = new();
}


public class ClassSeconda
{
public string Nome { get; set; }
public double Maggiore { get; set; }
public double Minore { get; set; }
}

The query I would like to get is this:
ClassProva dati = (from c in DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
where c.Field<Int32>("Ident") == Id
select new ClassProva ()
{
Name = c.Field<string>("Nome"),
Seconda.Nome = c.Field<string>("Nome_Seconda"),
Seconda.Maggiore = c.Field<double>("Maggiore"),
Seconda.Minore = c.Field<double>("Minore")
}).FirstOrDefault();

But it seems that it is not possible to do this:
Seconda.Nome


I believe you need to explicitly new up a ClassSeconda object inside the ClassProva initializer list, and then initialize its properties with a nested initializer list.
ClassProva dati = (
        from c in DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        where c.Field<Int32>("Ident") == Id
        select new ClassProva {
            Name = c.Field<string>("Nome"),
            Seconda = new ClassSeconda {
                Nome = c.Field<string>("Nome_Seconda"),
                Maggiore = c.Field<double>("Maggiore"),
                Minore = c.Field<double>("Minore")
            }
        }
    ).FirstOrDefault();

The default = new() can be dropped from the Seconda property definition, if not needed for other uses.
Do you also need to set the Id property?
